# ZF2, controller doesn't fill the form elements from hydrated objects that are attached to the form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

In ZF2, I have a form that has two fieldsets. The 2 fieldsets are basically for party-related info (party = person or company) and phone-related info. The fieldsets are called using the init method of the form like this

```
class PhoneRegistrationForm extends RegistrationForm implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this
            ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false))
            ->setObject(new Phone());

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Button',
            'name' => 'submitButton',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'submit-phone-button',
                'class' => 'btn2 submit-button',
                'type' => 'submit',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Сохранить',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Parties\Forms\Fieldsets\PhoneFieldset',
            'name' => 'phoneFieldset'
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Parties\Forms\Fieldsets\PartyIdAndRolesFieldset',
            'name' => 'partyFieldset'
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the controller's edit action, I create and hydrate the PhoneObject and PartyObject with the values from the database (PhoneObject and PartyObjects are just collection of getters and setters). I then set the hydrated objects to the fieldsets:

```
$this->form->get('phoneFieldset')->setObject($phone);
$this->form->get('partyFieldset')->setObject($party);
```

And here is my problem, if I return the instance of form to the controller, the form inputs have no values that come from the attached hydrated objects.

How to get the form inputs filled with the values from the hydrated objects attached to fieldsets?

I tried binding `$this->form->bind($phone)`, but to no avail. The fieldsets have `ClassMethods()` hydrator set too.

What could the problem be? Any clues?

EDIT: after answer by @hooli, this is the code for the fieldset that I use.

```
class PhoneFieldsetFactory extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __invoke(FormElementManager $formElementManager)
    {
        $this
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods())
            ->setObject(new Phone());

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'name' => 'id',
        ]);

        $this->add(
            $formElementManager
                ->get('Parties\Forms\Elements\ContactMechanismTypeSelect',
                    ['mechanismType' => 'телефон'])
        );

        $this->add(
            $formElementManager
                ->get('Parties\Forms\Elements\CountrySelect')
        );

        $this->add(
            $formElementManager
                ->get('Parties\Forms\Elements\ContactMechanismPurposeTypeMultiCheckbox',
                    ['mechanismType' => 'телефон'])
        );

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'areaCode',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'area-code',
                'placeholder' => '1234',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Код области'
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'phoneNbr',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'phone-nbr',
                'placeholder' => '1234567890',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Номер телефона',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'extension',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'extension',
                'placeholder' => '1234567890',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Добавочный',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'comment',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'comment',
                'placeholder' => 'общий телефон организации',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Примечание',
            ],
        ]);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understand for your problem :

when you declare this :

```
$this
        ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
        ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false))
        ->setObject(new Phone());
```

The PhoneRegistrationForm object when you'll use `bind` method will populate your Phone Object, but you didn't have any fields of your Phone Object in that direct PhoneRegistrationForm because you use a fieldset.

Then it's your fieldset  you should update to set the correct hydrator strategy.

Plus, it's the same solution for you other fieldset.

I usually use doctrine and entities, but it's the same logic.

Comment: thanks hooli, the problem is that the hydrators are also attached to the fieldsets (the `ClassMethods(false)` hydrator). I updated my question so that you can see the code for the fieldset.

Comment: reread your answer, and i'm not sure i follow you. you explain how the object hydration takes place, whereas i need to get the values FROM the object to the fieldset's inputs when, say, editing is needed. the hydrators are attached to the fieldsets (the `ClassMethods(false)`). i updated my question so that you can see the code for the fieldset. as a side note, i think if you use `bind` method of the form, the objects attached to the fieldsets get hydrated (at least it works for me this way).

Comment: The boolean you passed in you classMethod constructor is the $underscoreSeparatedKeys and it's defined by Zend as : Flag defining whether array keys are underscore-separated (true) or camel case (false) so it doesn't fit with what you tried

Comment: hooli, sorry, man, for some reason, i thought that underscoredseparatedkeys is false by default. i'll check your suggestion.

Comment: i set the `$underscoreSeparatedKeys` to `false`, but no difference: the values don't get passed from the already hydrated objects to the form's inputs...

Comment: Hmm you don't understad what i'm saying, you can set this value to whatever you want, it's not relative to hydrate your object => it just define the camel ou snake case keys of your class...

Comment: well, then i don't understand what you're saying. :) `ClassMethods` compares the form input names with the object's getters and setters and fills the corresponding protected properties of the objects. if `$underscoreSeparatedKeys = true` whereas the form input names are camel case, no hydration/extraction will happen. the `bind` method of the form, i guess,propagates the binding of the objects to the corresponding fieldsets. but the problem is that i don't understand how to transfer the values from the already hydrated objects to the form inputs when i use the `editAction()` on the form.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT A REALLY GOOD SOLUTION, PLEASE FEEL FREE TO SUGGEST BETTER VARIANTS! I WILL MAKE YOUR ANSWER ACCEPTED IF IT'S BETTER.

After a day of trials and errors still couldn't figure out why the form inputs don't get filled based on the objects attached to the fieldsets. I found, though, a workaround for this.

A ZF2 `Fieldset` implements the method `populateValues()`. If you use something like this

```
$this->form->get('neededFieldset')->populateValues(
    $this->form->getHydrator()->extract($objectWhoseValuesWillBeExtracted));
```

you'll have the form's inputs filled with the corresponding object's data.